# Name for a endpoint in a RESTfull way

Tags: rest

I am doing a application for a supermarket ,I am designing a endpoint that takes a articleId(an Item id) and return all similar articles and a representative article(has the logic of finding the earliest article within similar article) for that article Id.

I already have a resource end point for articles as /article/{articleid}

What is the best way to name for similars ?
(currently it is /article/similars.json&articleid=####)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a query parameter off the collection:

```
GET /articles?similarTo={articleId}
```

I'd also suggest that you use a plural (articles) instead of a singular (article) for your collection name. If you want back JSON, use the `Accept` header to indicate that, or, if you must, stick it on `/articles`:

```
GET /articles.json?simiarTo={articleId}
```

Comment: How can the endpoint also have the saying that it returns the representative article ?

Comment: @Raghavan I don't understand the question.

Comment: I was initially thinking that the endpoint must say it also returns representative article , now felt it is not needed . Thanks Eric